# pulling results from 2 tables where x and x match?

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to pull data from 2 tables like so

```
$query2 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM supplier_stats, supplier_registration WHERE supplier_stats.company_reg_number = supplier_registration.company_reg_number AND supplier_stats.insurance_date = DATE(NOW())");
        while($row = mysql_fetch_array( $query2 )) {
        echo "<div class=\"contact_details\">Supplier Contact Details:<br/>";    
        echo "<p>".$row['contact_name']."</p></div>";

        echo "<div class=\"contact_details\">Supplier Contact Details:<br/>";    
        echo "<p>".$row['contact_email']."</p></div>";

        } ?>
```

What I am trying to do is get the `insurance_date` from one table `supplier_stats` and the contact details from table `supplier_registration` and group these by the `company_number` which is in both tables, but this doesnt pull through anything, and I get no error.

Comment: It looks OK to me, except that implicit joins are considered poor style these days. Can you make a sqlfiddle with sample data?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$query2 = mysql_query("SELECT supplier_stats.* FROM supplier_stats, supplier_registration WHERE supplier_stats.company_reg_number = supplier_registration.company_reg_number AND supplier_stats.insurance_date =  CURDATE()");
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array( $query2 )) {
    echo "<div class=\"contact_details\">Supplier Contact Details:<br/>";    
    echo "<p>".$row['contact_name']."</p></div>";

    echo "<div class=\"contact_details\">Supplier Contact Details:<br/>";    
    echo "<p>".$row['contact_email']."</p></div>";

    } ?>
```

since company_reg_number is ambiguous in both tables, it will throw error
USE `CURDATE()` instead of `DATE(NOW())`

Also avoid using deprecated mysql_*

Answer (score 0):

Give your query a try like this:

```
SELECT ss.insurance_date, sr.contact_details 
FROM supplier_stats ss
JOIN supplier_registration sr ON sr.company_reg_number = ss.company_reg_number
WHERE ss.insurance_date = CURDATE()
```

Note that I replaced `*` with the two items you mentioned. Not sure if `contact details` is one field or many, but you can alter as needed. The point here is the `JOIN`.

Also, and this should go without saying, don't use `mysql_*` - instead you should use `mysqli` or `pdo`

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM supplier_stats AS ss
LEFT JOIN supplier_registration AS sr ON ss.company_reg_number = sr.company_reg_number 
WHERE ss.insurance_date = CURDATE();
```

Would probably sort that sql out.

Incidentally, I like a little [Heredoc](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc) action in these situations - makes the SQL string much easier to read.

And as said elsewhere, do discover the joys of [PDO](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php)

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
$query2 = mysql_query(" SELECT supplier_registration.contact_name, 
                               supplier_registration.contact_email 
                        FROM supplier_registration 
                        INNER JOIN supplier_stats
                        ON supplier_registration.company_reg_number = supplier_stats.company_reg_number
                        WHERE supplier_stats.insurance_date = DATE(NOW())");
```

Comment: what your change or what he did wrong can you explain ?